# Set Label of IntervalBarSeries (oxyplot)

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

[image]I'm trying to set my own labeltext placed on the IntervalBarSeries, but it only shows the ugly DateTime.ToDouble()-Value. `Title = "anyText"` doesn't affect anything.
Any ideas? Next problem is, that IntervalBarSeries does not have a Style property...

MCVE:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Label_Issue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Label_Issue"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="barChartModel"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.cs:

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Label_Issue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetUtilizationData();
        }

        public PlotModel PlotModel { get; set; }
        private void SetUtilizationData()
        {
            PlotModel = new PlotModel
            {
                LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Vertical,
                LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside,
                LegendPosition = LegendPosition.RightTop
            };


            // define x-axis
            OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis dateAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis
            {
                Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom,
                //StringFormat = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm"         // automatisch?
            };

            // add to plotmodel.axes
            PlotModel.Axes.Add(dateAxis);


            // define y-axis
            CategoryAxis categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            };

            //add to plotmodel.axes
            PlotModel.Axes.Add(categoryAxis);

            IntervalBarSeries barSeries = new OxyPlot.Series.IntervalBarSeries
            {
                LabelMargin = 0,
                LabelFormatString = "{0:.0}",
            };

            TestData td = new TestData();
            foreach (TestDataItem data in td)
            {
                IntervalBarItem item = new IntervalBarItem
                {
                    Start = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(data.start),
                    End = OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(data.end),
                    CategoryIndex = 0,
                    Title = "test"
                };
                barSeries.Items.Add(item);
            }

            PlotModel.Series.Add(barSeries);
            barChartModel.Model = PlotModel;
        }
    }
    public class TestData : ObservableCollection<TestDataItem>
    {
        public TestData()
        {
            Add(new TestDataItem()
            {
                start = new DateTime(2017, 04, 01, 06, 00, 00),
                end = new DateTime(2017, 04, 01, 06, 30, 00),
            });
        }
    }
    public class TestDataItem
    {

        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `MCVE`?

Comment: I added a MCVE with one barItem

Comment: I wrote an answer, if you will have any Q, just ping me in the [WPF chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this result, because you changed format for `LabelFormatString`:

```
IntervalBarSeries barSeries = new OxyPlot.Series.IntervalBarSeries
{
   LabelMargin = 0,
   LabelFormatString = "{0:.0}",
};
```

By default `LabelFormatString` has value: `{2}` (`Title`)

So, just remove it and then you will able to get correct result.

```
IntervalBarSeries barSeries = new OxyPlot.Series.IntervalBarSeries
{
   LabelMargin = 0
};
```